# Does it make sense for equals and compareTo to be inconsistent?

Tags: java, collections

I want to make a class usable in `SortedSet` | `SortedMap`.

```
class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass>{
  // the only thing relevant to comparisons:
  private final String name;

  //...
}
```

The class' instances must be sorted by their name property.
However, I don't want equally named instances to be considered as equal.

So a `SortedSet` content would look like **a, a, a, b, c**.
(Normally, `SortedSet` would only allow **a, b, c**)

**First of all: is this (philosophically) consistent?**

If so, do I have to expect unpredictable behavior, when I don't
override `equals(...)` and `hashCode()`?

**Edit:**
I am sorry, my question seems inconsistent:
I want to put **multiple "equal" values** inside a **set**, which doesn't allow this
by concept.
So, please don't reply to my question anymore.
Thanks to all who already replied.

Comment: Why not just use a different Collection type?

Comment: Yes, google-collection-API's MultiSet | MultiMap seems good for this.
I hope so much that the Sun, aehm, Oracle guys would someday add functionality to the Java collection API...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let me ask you a question: does it make sense to have `a.compareTo(b)` return 0 and `a.equals(b)` return `false`?

I would use a [`Comparator<MyClass>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) instead. This is why all `SortedMap`/`SortedSet` implementations that I know of allow you to pass in a `Comparator` at creation.

Comment: I would tend to answer: it makes no sense ;)

Thank you, I forgot that there's such thing as a Comparator ;)

Answer (score 4):

From the Javadoc for Comparable

> It is strongly recommended (though not
>   required) that natural orderings be
>   consistent with equals. This is so
>   because sorted sets (and sorted maps)
>   without explicit comparators behave
>   "**strangely**" when they are used with
>   elements (or keys) whose natural
>   ordering is inconsistent with equals

If you want to have compareTo inconsistent with equals(), it is recommended that you instead use an explicit comparator by providing a class that implements Comparator.

> If so, do I have to expect unpredictable behavior, when I don't override equals(...) and hashcode()?

You should still override equals() and hashcode().  Whether or not equals() and hashcode() are consistent with compareTo is a different matter.

Answer (score 2):

[Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) recommends that if you don't implement `compareTo` consistent with `equals` you should clearly indicate so:

> The recommended language is "Note:
>   This class has a natural ordering that
>   is inconsistent with equals."

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code in the equals method and dont ever think about it again:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) return true;
    if (!(obj instanceof MyClass)) return false;
    return 0 == this.compareTo((MyClass) obj);
}
```

Comment: But if you implement equals(), you must implement hashcode() also. Otherwise strange things can happen.

Comment: You can delegate hashCode to some other property or a method that returns a comparable int value. But dont bother, since hashCode is like checking if its a same reference, not if they have same value.